# python to c++ with pybind

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am passing a 4,4 numpy array from python to c++ using pybind, I am getting the data incorrect on c++ side . Can anyone correct me?

`Python side`

```
import modul as md
import bumpy as np 
md.send(np.eye(4))
```

`c++ side` I receive the array as `py::array_t<double> transfrom`

```
auto buf1 = transfrom.request();
cv::Mat m(buf1.shape[0], buf1.shape[1], CV_32F , (double*)buf1.ptr);
cv::Matx44f gtranform((float*)m.ptr());
cout << "transform  "<< gtranform <<endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and gave up on using `Mat`

```
auto buf1 = transfrom.request();.
double *ptr1 = (double *) buf1.ptr;
int X = buf1.shape[0];
int Y = buf1.shape[1];
Matx44f gtranform(X,Y);
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < X; idx++)
  for (size_t idy = 0; idy < Y; idy++)
    gtranform(idx,idy) = ptr1[idx*Y+ idy];
```

Hope this helps someone